# How to add a button below div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of div cards, side by side, using the display: inline-block, and what I'd like to do is when I click on a card, it adds a button **below** the div.

I'm using jquery's after() function to do that, but it's adding the button to the **right** of the div.

Please, how can I do that?

PS: I tried using the append function, but I have another function that removes the button when I click again on the div, so when I click on the button (which is now part of the div), it's like you clicked on the div, and the button is removed, so it doesn't work...

Thank you!

**Edit...**

thank you very much for the answers...

Sorry for not showing the code, here it is:

```
    <div class = "classOfDiv">
        here goes some product characteristics
    </div>


$('.classOfDiv').click(
    function() {
        //gets the border because I need it to see if I'm clicking for the first time or second time.
        var border = $(this).css("border");

        //checks the border
        if (border == "0px none rgb(51, 51, 51)") { 
            //change the border style to say that the div has been clicked
            $(this).css("border", "3px solid blue");
            //add the button
            $(this).after("<button name = 'btnDetalhes' class = 'btn btn-primary'>Detalhes</button>");  
        } else {
            //remove the border (now the div is diselected)
            $(this).css("border", "0px none rgb(51, 51, 51)");  
            //remove the button
            $(this).next("[name='btnDetalhes']").remove();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Can you post your code? You should think about just hiding/showing the buttons instead of trying to inject them into the html.

Comment: placing an element after another doesn't mean it gets displayed below the other one. That's what css is for... also read [ask]

Comment: so many solutions...that aren't possible without your code

Comment: About what @Shnibble said: hiding and showing a button instead of trying to inject into the HTML. I tried it already, using a button with display: none and calling the show method in the click of the div. What happens is: when the button is showed up (the div has been clicked) and then I click on the button, as the button is inside a div, the code calls the 'else' (because we`re clicking on the div for the second time) and remove the button before it`s action.
This is why I wanted to add the button outside the div, so that the .click function of the div is not called when I hit the button...

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post with the code.

Comment: `@foreach($drinks as $drink)` what language is that?

Comment: @GabrielAugusto can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this is PHP, using Laravel Framework

Comment: @GabrielAugusto thx! Never used Laravel.

Comment: np. Trying to create the Minimal, Complete, Verifiable exampl, I edited the HTML, but the Javascript I think is already the minimum. 

I hope you guys got the point: if I use the `after()` function, It works, but the button is on the right of the div. 
On the other hand, If I declare the button inside the div (hidden), and then show the button when I click the div, I will need to hide it when I click the div again. It doesn`t allow me to click on the button, because when I click it, the div will hide it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have an actual answer yet, here is a really rough concept for how to do what I was suggesting with show/hiding.

You will need to specify what "hides" the button div. If it should be clicking on the card again then just change `show()` to `toggle`

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

.card-button {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -22px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="card" onclick="$('.card-button').show()">
    <p>Card Content</p>
    <div class="card-button" onclick="alert('button clicked!')">
      <span>BUTTON</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As per the conversation, an alternative solution is to use `event.stopPropogation()` in your event handler to keep the click on the button from triggering other parent's click events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That`s the idea, the only problem is that when I click on the button for the first time, it changes the border of that div and shows the button. Okay until now. But, when I hit the div again, it has paints the border back to normal border and removes the button. 
And when I click on the button it behaves like you clicked on the div, so the button will disappear. That`s the main problem... Is there a way to ignore the behave of the div when I click on the button?

Comment: You really need to post your complete code for anyone to give a complete solution. I think I understand the issue you are having, and it can be resolved with `event.stopPropogation()` being added to your click event handler. But without seeing your code it is hard to say exactly where it should fit in.

Comment: Thanks, dude. event.stopPropagation() solved my problem!

Would you like to post as an answer? So that I can check it as an answer?

Im sorry about the code, I thought the code on the description was enought, but you got the problem and solved it. 

Using the event.stopPropagation() prevents the div to be clicked at the moment I click on the button, so worked as a charm!

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer to include it. Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    
    $(".card").click(function () { 
     $(this).append('<a class="button" href="#">Button</a>');
 });
    
   
});
```

```css
.card{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:40px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.button{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">a</div>
<div class="card">b</div>
<div class="card">c</div>
<div class="card">d</div>
<div class="card">e</div>
<div class="card">f</div>
<div class="card">g</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written spoiler BBCodes for forums before; the concept is essentially the same, so flip them and you get:

```html
<span>
<div onclick="var s=this.parentNode.querySelector('button');s.style.display=s.style.display==''?'none':''">
<!-- put stuff here -->
</div>
<button type="button" style="display:none"><!-- put other stuff here --></button>
</span>
```